# NPE when converting dom to bytes with LS

Tags: java, dom

I am trying to convert a dom node to bytes with below code (jdk1.8.0_40) :

```
    DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS = (DOMImplementationLS) (node instanceof Document ? ((Document) node) : node.getOwnerDocument()).getImplementation().getFeature("LS", "3.0");
    LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
    lsSerializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", prettyPrint);
    LSOutput lsOutput = domImplementationLS.createLSOutput();
    lsOutput.setEncoding(UTF_8.toString());

    ByteArrayOutputStream writer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    lsOutput.setByteStream(writer);
    lsSerializer.write(node, lsOutput);
```

This results in a NPE:

```
org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl.write(DOMSerializerImpl.java:844)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl.prepareForSerialization(DOMSerializerImpl.java:1063)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl.write(DOMSerializerImpl.java:747) ... 40 more
```

Is this a bug in java or am I doing something wrong?

*Update*:
I found out that when I get the document element it works:

```
lsSerializer.write((node instanceof Document ? ((Document) node) : node.getOwnerDocument()), lsOutput);
```

The java doc states: *The node to serialize*, but it seems this can not be a Document node.